# How to set/find user roles from Organization based Identity in .NET core

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to find out what role(s) a user has within a Blazor Server app that has Authentication setup for an organization that uses MS accounts and Azure Active Directory. I would imagine that the roles are set by the IT Operations team managing the MS accounts, but I'm not finding where to verify that at.

So I would like to know: *where are roles set when using Org authentication*, *how can I change them*, *and is there a simple way to see what roles an authenticated user has*?

I tried looking for an authenticated user's role in the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) example code using the cascade parameter like below:

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="LogUsername">Log username</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        LogUsername();
    }

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var test = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type.Contains("Role")); // also tried "role"
            string role = test.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"{role} is authenticated.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Identity has a `RoleClaimType` but I can't find anything else that would tell what the Role for a given user is. Am I looking in the wrong spot for this maybe? I couldn't find any detailed docs on how Organiztion Authentication works with Identity in .NET core and Blazor, so any tips, advice, or nudges in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roles are set in the azure portal. Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> [your app] -> Roles and Administrators. For custom roles, your organization will need Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 licenses.

As for how to retrieve them, here is a quote from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles#implementation):

> Get role claims. When a user signs in, the application receives the
>   user's assigned role(s) in a claim with type
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role (the
>   roles claim in a JWT token).
>
> A user can be assigned multiple roles, or no role. In your
>   authorization code, don't assume the user has exactly one role claim.
>   Instead, write code that checks whether a particular claim value is
>   present:
>
> `if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

```
var Roles = User.Claims.Where(t => t.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 2):

for those who are looking like me, in .Net 6

official documentation how to enable roles in Blazor [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

close the component for viewing

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">  
    <div> ..... </div>
</AuthorizeView>
```

get the name of the user's first role

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
       <p>@context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Type == "role").Value</p>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

close page from view

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Normal")]
```

Comment: How do we get the role inside the @code in blazor?